# What framework should I use for a game in Silverlight and on the client?

Tags: silverlight, client

I made a couple simple games in Silverlight.  I'm considering making a much deeper game for Windows.  It would have a feature limited version available in Silverlight for use in the browser.  What would you recommend I use for the client application (not in a browser or Silverlight)?

If any additional information is required, I'll try to add it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WPF seems like the obvious choice.  Since Silverlight is itself a subset of WPF the games and code you already have would be easily portable into whatever application you set up.  You could even just wrap your main page in a window and probably run it.

If you don't want to use WPF for the Client App, then please try to state the reasons, (cross-platform, etc.)

Comment: I intended to use as much of the same code-base as possible.  I consider WPF to be a good option, but I thought something else may be better.  I wasn't sure about XNA or other framworks.